# Install two Java 6 updates on the same computer

Tags: windows, windows-xp, java

I need to install two updates of Java 6 JRE on the same Windows XP computer (the 10 and the last one = 30) but i can't : even if i ask for another folder destination, it owerwrites the installed version !

Thanks a lot

Comment: What are you *actually* trying to do? ("what do you need two different JREs for?") This sounds very much like an [X-Y Problem](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=542341).

Comment: @Piskvor I needed multiple JRE versions for testing against specific JRE revisions. But I used JDKs to get them to avoid issues like OP has.

Comment: The problem is that the Java system property `java.home` is derived from Windows registry (which stores all JRE distributions with emphasis on the latest JRE installation) instead of `JAVA_HOME` environment variable for the JRE distribution. `JAVA_HOME` is only used in the JDK distribution. Extracting JRE distribution into a separate folder won't do anything unless you pass `-Djava.home` to the JAVA command line with given folder before running a Java program.

Comment: You can install just by unzipping jre. You may delete entries (java.exe ) from C:\windows\System32. Why?  See http://mindprod.com/jgloss/javaexe.html

Comment: @Dave Newton: I'm not saying there is no need for multiple JREs on one machine; I'm just checking if that's actually necessary, or if the end goal could be reached in another way. (Sometimes it is, sometimes not; many times, clearing this up could save *a lot* of unnecessary hassle)

Comment: Didn't my answer solve your problem ?

Answer (score 3):

Do not **INSTALL** it, just **EXTRACT** the zip files of the JRE and then:

- Where you need the **6.10**, u guide it to `C:\directory_of_6.10`
- When you need the **6.30**, you guide it to `C:\directory_of_6.30`

**UPDATE:**

For setting the right JRE in **eclipse** or at the **command line**, please read the comments on this answer.

Comment: Don't forget to reassign `java.home` property using `-Djava.home` to refer to the JRE folder that you want it to refer to from the command line of java.exe or javaw.exe. Don't forget to append the folder into the `PATH` environment variable as well. But, I would prefer to append `%JAVA_HOME%` into the PATH so that you can assign `JAVA_HOME` environment variable with the given JRE folder to avoid java.exe or javaw.exe version confusion.

Comment: @eee He never said he was using the Command Prompt. Actually if he uses Eclipse, he only has to change it in the porject properties, etc.

Comment: I agree with your point but I feel the need to tell a little bit when executing a Java program via command prompt instead of Eclipse..just to appreciate what is really needed to do so. In Eclipse, everything is just peanut!

Comment: @eee Be my guest and edit my answer the way you like and I will accept your valuable addition :)

Comment: Instead, I will let you do that but it is not necessary since we already have the comments :)

Comment: HEHEHE, I wish I had the time or the power (I'm pretty sleep to think about what to add, and how to add)

Comment: Haha, I am in the midst of enjoying my cup noodle ...OK, I will stop my chat here :)